# How to restrict access to specific work item functions in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I need to restrict access to a group in VSTS (let's say Contributors for now), such that they can do everything except:

1) Delete work items

2) Edit links within work item to other work items

3) Change status of work items

Question: Is this possible in VSTS and if so, how do I achieve it?

I've had a look at the following pages, but I haven't managed to get the exact setup above that I require.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/change-individual-permissions?view=vsts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=vsts#set-permissions-area-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent deletion of work items by setting "Not Set" for "Delete and restore work items"in the team project security tab. When you set "Not Set" for "Edit work items in this node" for a given area path, work items of that area path cannot be edited. But if you want a user to edit other things such as description, title and prevent him from editing the status and linking other work items, that is not a possibility in VSTS permission structure. Instead of "Not Set" usage of Deny is possible but Deny is getting high priority and it is possible that you may run into issues, if you try to add a user who is having a Deny applied to another group which is having permissions set to Allow. Using "Not Set" is safer.

Comment: Thanks. That’s pretty much what I got up to before posting the question. Would be good if VSTS did support granular permissions.

Comment: Be careful with Deny: better using Not Set whenever possible or you will caught by surprise.